# Basic programming exercise about logical operators

Tags: c, logical-operators

I have a problem with a question in my book:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a=5, b=-7, c=0, d;
    d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
    printf("\n%d%d%d%d",a,b,c,d);
}
```

The question asks me what is the output of the code. I ran it and the result on the screen is 6-601. I understand why `a=6` and `b=-6`, but I don't understand why `c=0` and `d=1`?

Comment: Your answer got accepted. That's about as much proof as you would need. I sometimes wonder if I'm not overdoing it, when I write an answer like that, and by the time I'm done, someone has written a 'Try this `<threelinesofcode>`' answer that got accepted instead.

Comment: @GolezTrol I think sir you meant to post this comment under my answer, however, thank you. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ah, that's where that comment went! I meant to post it under [your question on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313420/how-much-explanation-is-good-am-i-overdoing-it), but then I couldn't find it anymore. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you already got your answer, but just to elaborate a bit step-by-step, let me add one more clarification here. Firstly, to quote the properties of the `&&` and `||` operators, from `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.13 and §6.5.13, respectively,

(I)

> The `&&` operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it
>   yields 0. [...] If the first operand compares **equal to 0**, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.

and

(II)

> The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it
>   yields 0.  [...]. If the first operand compares **unequal to 0**, the second operand is
>   not evaluated.

and they both guarantee left-to-right evaluation. So, comparing your code,

```
d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
```

it happens like

```
d = ((++a && ++b) || ++c );
```

which evaluates to

```
d = (( 6 && ++b ) || ++c);
```

and then

```
d = ( ( 6 && (-6) ) || ++c);
```

Now in above stage, (I) is fulfilled and it comes down to

```
d = ( 1 || ++c);
```

Now, following the emphasis, which already meets the (II), so no further evaluation of the RHS operand of `||` is performed (i.e., `++c` is not evaluated), and it appears to be `d = 1` and the final result, 1, is stored into `d`.

That's how, `a == 6`, `b == -6`, `c == 0` and `d ==1`.

---

Having said that, `void main()` should be changed to `int main(void)`, at least to conform with the standard.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear, but i'm confused between void main() and int main(void), the code above i just copied directly from my book.

Comment: @Hoang.T there is very good discussion posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/2173917). Do read it. :)

Answer (score 14):

The `||` OR operator is short-circuiting, which means that if the left side is true then the right side is not evaluated. In this case `++a && ++b` evaluates to true, so `++c` is never run and `c` keeps its value of zero.

Also since it evaluates to true, this is denoted with `1` which is stored in `d`.

Any non-zero value is considered to be true and the result of boolean operations is defined to be `0` or `1` as an integer.